# GridView Disappears on Update Button Click, Doesn't Update Record

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, gridview, kentico

So I have a c# page with a GridView. For some reason, after adding the label and the template for editing, when I click the update button in the edit column, the GridView disappears and none of the records get changed. I know I need to databind the values in the edit box once the user clicks update but I'm not sure how. Can anyone give any suggestions?

Here is my code.

```
public partial class CMSWebParts_Custom_Development_DevWebPart : 
CMSAbstractWebPart
{

public string paramId;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        ViewState["RefUrl"] = Request.UrlReferrer.ToString();
    }
    string urlString = Request.UrlReferrer.ToString();
    paramId = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(urlString).Get("Theid");

    DispatchNumberLabel.Text = getDispatchNumber();
    //TerminalLabel.Text = getTerminal();
    DispatchInfoIdLabel.Text = getDispatchInfoId();
    DriverNameLabel.Text = getDriverName();
}

protected string getDispatchInfoId()
{
    string result = DriverDropDownList.SelectedValue;
    return result;
}

protected string getDispatchNumber()
{
    string result = paramId;
    return result;
}

protected string getTerminal()
{
    string result;
    string connectionString = "";
    using (var con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        var sql = "Select Terminal from Form_IntranetSharpTransit_DispatchInfo where ([Dispatch] = @Dispatch)";         
        using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Dispatch", getDispatchNumber());
            con.Open();
            result = (string)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        }
    }
    return result;
}

protected string getDriverName()
{
    string result;
    string connectionString = "";
    using (var con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        var sql = "Select Driver from Form_IntranetSharpTransit_DispatchInfo WHERE ([DispatchInfoID] = @DispatchInfoId)";
        using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DispatchInfoId", getDispatchInfoId());
            con.Open();
            result = (string)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        }
    }
    return result;
} 
}
```

And here is my code behind.

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" 
CodeFile="~/CMSWebParts/Custom/Development/DevWebPart.ascx.cs" 
Inherits="CMSWebParts_Custom_Development_DevWebPart" %>
<%--<script runat="server">

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
</script>--%>Dispatch Number:
<asp:Label ID="DispatchNumberLabel" runat="server"></asp:Label>
<p>
Terminal:
<asp:Label ID="TerminalLabel" runat="server"></asp:Label>
</p>
<p>
Current
Dispatch Info ID:
<asp:Label ID="DispatchInfoIdLabel" runat="server"></asp:Label>
</p>
<p>
&nbsp;Driver Name:
<asp:Label ID="DriverNameLabel" runat="server"></asp:Label>
</p>
<asp:DropDownList ID="DriverDropDownList" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
DataSourceID="DriverListData" DataTextField="Select Driver" 
DataValueField="Column1">
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="DriverListData" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ 
ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" ProviderName="<%$ 
ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString.ProviderName %>" SelectCommand="Select 
'', 'Select Driver' as 'Select Driver'
from Form_IntranetSharpTransit_DispatchInfo
Union
SELECT     DispatchInfoID, Driver + ' - ' + CAST(DispatchInfoID AS 
varchar(50)) AS Expr1
FROM         Form_IntranetSharpTransit_DispatchInfo 
WHERE     (Dispatch = ?) AND (DaysOff NOT LIKE '%' + (SELECT DispatchDay 
FROM Form_IntranetSharpTransit_DailyDispatch Where DailydispatchID = ?) + 
'%') AND (Status LIKE 'Available')">
<SelectParameters>
    <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="?" QueryStringField="Theid" />
    <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="?" QueryStringField="Theid" />
</SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
AutoGenerateEditButton="True" DataSourceID="Store1Data" EditIndex="0" 
OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged">
<Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Store 1:">
        <EditItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
OnTextChanged="TextBox1_TextChanged" Text='<%# Bind("[Store Number]") %>'>
</asp:TextBox>
        </EditItemTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("[Store 
Number]") %>'></asp:Label>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="Store1Data" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ 
ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" ProviderName="<%$ 
ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString.ProviderName %>" SelectCommand="SELECT     
(SELECT     Store
                   FROM          Form_IntranetSharpTransit_TourPlan
                   WHERE      (TourPlanID = 
Form_IntranetSharpTransit_DispatchInfo_1.Store1)) AS 'Store Number', 
Location1, Pro1, Store1Export
FROM         Form_IntranetSharpTransit_DispatchInfo AS 
Form_IntranetSharpTransit_DispatchInfo_1
WHERE     (DispatchInfoID = ?)">
<SelectParameters>
    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DriverDropDownList" Name="?" 
PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
</SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

All I want is to display the table with an edit button. When the edit button is clicked, I want the label in table to become an edit box (as my template shows). After the user has  modified the edit box, they can then click the update button, committing the change to the database and refreshing the table to show the changed values.

This seems extremely simple but I have been struggling with it for about 3 months now.

Please help.

Comment: First thing that comes to mind... are you setting `Store1Data` on Load? I'm thinking that `Store1Data` gets reset on `Postback`.

Comment: I dont set anything on load except for some local variables I pull from the URL and some queries. Would the way to remedy this be to put something like "Store1Data.DataBind()" be appropriate?

Comment: `<asp:SqlDataSource ID="Store1Data" runat="server"` is in the front-end code, setting `Store1Data` to a new value every time you load the page. You want to set the initial value of `Store1Data` on pageLoad, but you don't want to set it again on `PostBack`. Instead of loading the data into `Store1Data` from the front-end code, try setting it in the codeBehind and control when and how its gets updated through handling PostBacks.

Comment: I looked into this but didn't have any luck finding a solution to my problem, but I did learn about data binding my data sources properly, so thank you for that. I was able to get one of the entries to write the number '18' through the entire store1 column, which has delayed my work on this project since I've been fixing all the mucked up entries in the database :\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a minimal, yet working, example of what you are trying to achieve.
Though I must admit, the [Microsoft Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview(v=vs.110).aspx) came in pretty handy for this snippet.

Default.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="UpdateGridViewOnPostBack_45921943.Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="dgv1" AutoGenerateEditButton="true" OnRowEditing="dgv1_RowEditing" OnRowUpdating="dgv1_RowUpdating">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="gvCol1Label" Text='<%#Bind("field1") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="gvCol1Txtbx" Text='<%# Bind("field1") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Default.aspx.cs

```
using System;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace UpdateGridViewOnPostBack_45921943
{
    public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        static ObservableCollection<dgvEntry> dgv1Source;

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                //Not a postback
                dgv1Source = new ObservableCollection<dgvEntry>();
                dgv1Source.Add(new dgvEntry { field1 = "the field coming from the data source" });
                initializeDGV(IsPostBack);
            }
            else
            {
                //is a postback
                if (dgv1Source == null)
                {
                    dgv1Source = new ObservableCollection<dgvEntry>();
                }
                initializeDGV(IsPostBack);
            }
        }

        private void initializeDGV(bool isPostback)
        {
            dgv1.DataSource = dgv1Source;
            dgv1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
            if (!isPostback)
            {
                dgv1.DataBind();
            }
        }

        protected void dgv1_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
        {
            dgv1.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
            dgv1.DataBind();
        }

        protected void dgv1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
        {

            GridViewRow row = dgv1.Rows[e.RowIndex];
            dgv1Source[e.RowIndex].field1 = ((TextBox)row.Cells[1].Controls[1]).Text;
            dgv1.EditIndex = -1;
            dgv1.DataBind();
        }
    }

    public class dgvEntry
    {
        public string field1 { get; set; }
        //public string field2 { get; set; }
        //public string field3 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for putting this together, I will have a look!

Comment: After studying this I was able to implement the logic into my code and have succeeded in writing to the database. I do have one question however; in doing this I was forced to set Store1Data.UpdateCommand in the code behind. I used this: "Store1Data.UpdateCommand = "INSERT blah blah VALUES (@DispatchInfoId)" but I need to then figure out how to set @DispatchInfoId (the variable in the update query I'm running) to the result of the method getDispatchInfoId(), is this possible?

Comment: @MarleyStacy, Something like this should work `dataadapt.UpdateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DispatchInfoId", getDispatchInfoId());`

Comment: That's the ticket! Well, almost. Had to assign getDispatchInfoId() on pageload and then use that variable. Awesome! Thank you so much! SERIOUSLY! This is pretty huge for my companies bizarrely laid out intranet portal! Exactly what I needed. I upvoted it just won't show since I have no reputation.

Comment: Glad I could help!